# Set Individual Title of UIButtons in IBOutletCollection

Tags: ios, uibutton, iboutletcollection

Does anybody know how to set the title of each individual button in an array of buttons using an IBOutletCollection? This is what I have tried, but the code sets the title of all the buttons. I have connected the outlet to the buttons and set their respective tags.

```
.h file
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttonCollection;

.m file
- (IBAction)switchAction:(id)sender {

    for (UIButton *btn in buttonCollection) {
        if (btn.tag == 0) {
            [btn setTitle:@"1st Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } else if (btn.tag == 1) {
            [btn setTitle:@"2nd Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       } else if (btn.tag == 2) {
           [btn setTitle:@"3rd Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       }
}
```

Comment: What does it set the titles to? Are you saying that all the buttons get the same title?

Comment: No, whenever I tap a button the code immediately sets the titles of all the buttons: button 1 is set to 1st Button and button 2 is set to 2nd Button etc. Sorry if I were' clear enough in my question.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Set the title of only the button you clicked on?

Comment: Yes, exactly. When I tap the 2nd button, the code should only set the title of that button and when I tap the 1st button it should only set the title that button etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to set the title of the button you've clicked on, get rid of the for loop,

```
- (IBAction)switchAction:(UIButton *)sender {

     if (sender.tag == 0) {
          [sender setTitle:@"1st Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     } else if (sender.tag == 1) {
          [sender setTitle:@"2nd Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     } else if (sender.tag == 2) {
         [sender setTitle:@"3rd Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [buttonCollection count]; ++i)
{
    [((UIButton*)self.buttonCollection[i]) setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d button", i] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply, but it doesn't do what I want. See comments above. Sorry if I weren't too clear. It now works: see 2nd answer :)