# Swift: Set properties to an Extension of IBOutletCollection containing UIButtons

Tags: uibutton, nsarray, iboutletcollection

How can I set properties to an "extension" of an "IBOutletCollection" containing "UIButtons"?  I am trying to do this in a similar way that one can do with an extension UIButton, that does not seem to extend to a collection of UIButtons.  I hope to be as thorough and clear as possible.

Although there are similar questions:

1.[Change the color of UIButton in IBOutletCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459933/change-the-color-of-uibutton-in-iboutletcollection)

2.[Set Individual Title of UIButtons in IBOutletCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867120/set-individual-title-of-uibuttons-in-iboutletcollection)

...and numourous others. I still am not grasping how to do this, and can really use help that any of you can provide.

Here is what I have gathered so far:

1. An IBOutletCollection is always an NSArray.
2. Use a for-in-loop to iterate through the array’s content.

Here is my code example:  ( I have tried replacing where “Array” is with:  “NSArray” & “Collection” with “Collection” working similar to “Array”)

```
//Inside the main viewController:

@IBOutlet var ButtonCollection: [UIButton]!
```

```
//Inside the extention file:

extension Array where Element == UIButton
{
    func sharedButtonProperties()
    {
        for button in ButtonCollection
        {
            self.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
           //MARK: More properties will go here, once I get this to work. 
        }
    }
}
```

```
//calling the code inside main viewController, within "viewDidAppear"

ButtonCollection.sharedButtonProperties()
```

Now here is an example of an extension of a single IBOutlet of a UIButton that is working just fine, but not with a Collection:

```
//Inside the main viewController:

@IBOutlet weak var ButtonSingle: UIButton?
```

```
//Inside the extention file:

extension UIButton
{
    func buttonProperties()
        {
            self.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
        }
}
```

```
//calling the code inside main viewController, within "viewDidAppear"

ButtonSingle?.buttonProperties()
```

I am not an expert coder for sure, any help provided is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the solution after so much trial and error.  I want to share the answer with anybody that needs to set properties to **UIButtons** within an **IBOutletCollection**.  This is a very efficient way to cut down time when you want to set/define properties to a group of buttons, or to all buttons project-wide.

I really hope someone finds this useful!

Code (Tested & Works):  Note that what is in **bold** is what changed from the code I had in question.

```
//Inside the main viewController

@IBOutlet var ButtonCollection: [UIButton]!
```

```
//Inside the extention file:

extension Array where Element == UIButton
{
    func sharedButtonProperties()
    {
        for **buttonGrp** in **self**
        {
            **buttonGrp**.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
           //MARK: More properties will go here now! 
        }
    }
}
```

```
//calling the code inside main viewController, within "viewDidAppear"

ButtonCollection.sharedButtonProperties()
```

As you can see: I almost had it figured out, but all that was needed was to call the “buttonGrp” for the “for-in-loop", and to set this in “self”.  I hope that makes sence!

Bye bye!